# mixed-type, variable length argument list (varargin, *args, ...) for C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am building a C++ clone of a project originally written in MATLAB. I'd like to "translate" the code keeping as close to the original as possible (given the unavoidable differences between a dynamically typed language like MATLAB and a statically typed language like C++).

My question is about variable length argument lists as function parameters which can contain arguments of mixed type.

MATLAB has `varargin` as a function parameter:

```
 varargin Variable length input argument list.
    Allows any number of arguments to a function.  The variable
    varargin is a cell array containing the optional arguments to the
    function.  varargin must be declared as the last input argument
    and collects all the inputs from that point onwards. In the
    declaration, varargin must be lowercase (i.e., varargin).
```

In Python, `*args` and `**kwargs` handle this very comfortably.

How close can I get to this kind of flexibility in C++? Are there any standard argument list classes I should use?

Comment: See stdarg.h http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h or cstdarg.

Comment: Beyond the *ellipsis* (`printf` style) you can also use variadic templates that allow for a type safe version (resolved at compile time)

Comment: On the actual task at hand, matlab can actually generate C or C++ code. Not the prettiest, but you can avoid quite a bit of pain by just using it. I bet that the `varargin` is just using *ellipsis*, but let the tool do that for you.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I have researched MATLAB automatic code generation and came to the conclusion that generating object-oriented code is not possible. (Classes are among the language constructs for which code generation is not supported by MATLAB Coder) If you think I'm mistaken, I'd be very interested in code generation solutions.

Comment: AFAIK there are options in the generator to avoid global state and rather have it passed as arguments to the generated functions (all very C-like, I know), if you use that, then you can write a very simple wrapper around the matlab code that adds objects if you really feel the need. The objects would maintain the state, and the member functions would call the generated code passing the state from member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to pass arguments of a few (simple) types, `std::vector<>` passed as argument is pretty straightforward and easy.

Usually you will create struct such as:

```
struct Option {
    union {
        int Int;
        float Float;
    } Number;
    string String;
};
```

Optionally, you could add a `Type` field to the Option struct, for use in `switch` statements.

In C++11 it should be even possible to use std::string in an union, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

`<cstdarg>` is another solution, and is nice if you are using C functions such as `vsprintf`.

Comment: Yup, that would work too. I am still a bit careful when suggesting boost to someone with cases as simple as that.

Comment: Same here.  Unfortunately, this type of variant storage is not as simple as it first appears.